# color conversion error after one page using ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript 9.07 to convert a PDF file from color to gray using a batch-script. The script works and converts from color to gray but just for the first page. On every PDF I tried (12 PDFs) the conversion strategy reverts back to leave color unchanged after the first page.

Script:

```
C:\working-environment\gs9.07\bin\gswin64c -o C:\Test\converted.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dLastPage=20 -dColorConversionStrategy=/Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray C:\Test\original.pdf
```

Note: I am running the script on a Windows 7 PC as Administrator. The -dLastPage parameter is set because i have very long PDFs (500+ pages).

Error:

```
Unable to convert color space to Gray. reverting strategy to LeaveColorUnchanged.
```

Note:
I used the Oracle and Postgress manuals because i want to see the performance too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly the 'subsequent' page is using a colour space which, as the message informs you, cannot be converted to DeviceGray. Without seeing the file (and I really don't want a 500+ page file as an example) I can't tell you what is causing you the problem. If you can make a small file which exhibits this I'll look at it.

Please note that this is not an error, its a warning. An error would abort the job.

New colour management in the next release of Ghostscript should mean this no longer occurs anyway.

[EDIT]

For me this file gives the warning on the first page, no matter whether I use the current code or the released 9.07. Because the problem with the colour space occurs late on in the page content, all the content prior to this is indeed converted to Gray, but subsequent content is not.

The problem occurs because the PDF file uses a /Separation /All colour space to draw the 'printers marks' on the page. The current code cannot convert the /Separation colour space, nor can it preserve it, and so it reverts to 'leave colour unchanged'. Because the printers marks are the last thing on the page, and because /All marks all the plates and therefore seems to be black, it appears that the whole of the page has been converted, but this is not the case.

By splitting the file into 3 individual pages, you are getting what appears to be three individual 'correct' pages, but in fact each is partially converted and still contains the printers marks in /Separation /All.

The current code in the Ghostscript Git repository, when set to use the new CMS scheme, does convert this file without warnings and handles the multi-page file ostensibly correctly, but this code is as yet incomplete. It should be released with GS 9.08.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, here is the [test PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fghiwjbyk619va2/test.pdf) - only 3 pages. If I split every page into a single file, convert the single files and then merge it to one file again it works but that can not be the best and most performant solution. If I run my script on the whole document the color conversion strategy reverts back to leave color unchanged after SUCESSFULLY converting the first page.

Comment: @michael.niix PDF doesn't exist so can't check any of these answers using your source

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Ghostscript 9.06. Using `pdftops -level3sep` to convert the document to CMYK colours before passing it to Ghostscript solved it for me. Example in bash:

```
gs -o converted.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dColorConversionStrategy=/Gray \
  -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray <(pdftops -level3sep input.pdf -)
```

Also try:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
  -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dUseCIEColor -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: Had the same trouble with gs 9.10. Your answer saved me. Thank you!

Comment: neither of these worked for me, Ubuntu 14.04 with ghostscript 9.10.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to open a bug report. Casting about for partial solutions/workarounds/kludges isn't a good way to operate, if there is a problem I would far rather understand and fix it. I can't do that without seeing the file. However, the first thing you should try is updating to the **current** version of Ghostscript which is 9.16, 9.10 is 2 years old and there have, of course, been fixes to bugs which have been reported.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the information already here: this is still an issue in GS version 9.10, potentially having to do with the presence of EPS files. The way to work around this is to force it to use the old color management code.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
   -dOverrideICC -dPDFUseOldCMS=false
```

This bug report has more info: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694608